# how to remove peripheral device from devices and printers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, peripherals

I want to remove device specific device attached to my computer when i run a script in python but am not able to do this. Have searched on the web with no solution.
[link 1](https://gist.github.com/TakesTheBiscuit/a2e3d36c1d20731821fdb41b3831406e)  and
[link 2](https://github.com/iamgyz/usbEjector/blob/master/usb_eject.py)

I learnt i can achieve that with power shell but am not able to achieve that.

This code is able to open the cd rom successfully

```
import os

os.system('powershell $driveEject = New-Object -comObject Shell.Application; $driveEject.Namespace(17).ParseName("""F:""").InvokeVerb("""Eject""")')
```

I came across this question  [how to remove printer from devices and printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69158960/removing-printer-from-devices-and-printers-with-powershell) which there is no answer for it.

I kindly need assistance achieve such result.

[image: image display of what i want to remove or eject from devices and printers]

Comment: So you just want to eject the peripherals **physically** attached to your computer?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala yes to eject it using script.

Comment: check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56550602/14903754)

Comment: Looks like you are using Windows 7. Which PowerShell version do you use? You can get the version by issuing `$PSVersionTable` in PowerShell.

Comment: @stackprotector this is the version  `PSVersion   2.0`

Answer (score 0):

First I prepared a powershell script (s.ps1):

```
$driveEject = New-Object -comObject Shell.Application
$driveEject.Namespace(17).ParseName("E:").InvokeVerb("Eject")
```

Then I created a Python script

```
import os
os.system('powershell.exe -Command  ./s.ps1  >log.txt')
```

After that I got an error in the log file

```
./s.ps1 : s.ps1 cannot be loaded because
running scripts is disabled on this system. For
more information, see about_Execution_Policies at 
http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ ./s.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

After reading the [article](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170) I executed the commands in `cmd` running under the `administrator`

```
> powershell
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2015 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
 
PS >  Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

After that, I was finally able to run the script. And I saw a pop-up in the tray with a message that I can eject the disk.

[image]

Comment: am not trying to eject usb drive but peripheral device under devices and printer.

Comment: an algorithm will be same, but a powerscript will be different. I have just tablet and can't test

Comment: when you parse the device name it doesn't eject it.
  `Namespace(17).ParseName("S2-TEK TV")`

Comment: my answer about rights to run script, not about current script to dismount "S2-TEK TV", 
unfortunately, I don't have a single device to connect to the tablet to check which script is needed.

Comment: I think - script may be like **Get-PnpDevice | Where-Object {$ _. FriendlyName -like ‘*S2-TEK TV*’} | Disable-PnpDevice -Confirm: $ false.**

Comment: getting this error  `Where-Object' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241958/discussion-between-daniil-loban-and-o-joe).